# How do I use MySQL to create databases that remain even after system shutdown?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed xampp on my 64bit windows 10.
When I use command prompt to access MySQL, my previously created accounts are never there to log in with. When I do log in with root details and create databases, they are created. The moment I stop the server and start it again, all my databases are gone. 
Any help with this? 
My server version is mariaDb.

Comment: In mariadb databases do stay around, you do not need to do anything extra.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is it your databases, or your accounts, that come up missing? Does this happen after reboot, or just when you try to log in? Your root account has access to all databases, but the account you created might not. Have you read this? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html  Did you tell MySQL to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` immediately after creating your accounts?

Comment: Everything goes away. Accounts and databases.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.  You created them as "root".  But when you logged in as "samuel" to use them, you were not allowed to even see that they exist.  Learn about granting permissions.

Perhaps (while logged in as "root"):

```
CREATE DATABASE samual_db;    -- (you already did this)
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON samuel_db.* TO samuel@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';
```

Then, when logged in as 'samuel':

```
SHOW DATABASES;  -- should list it
USE samual_db;   -- to get 'into' that db
```

Now you can do things like

```
CREATE TABLE foo (...);
INSERT INTO foo ...;
SELECT * FROM foo;
```